# Float formatting in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout

How do you format a float in C++ to output to two decimal places rounded up? I'm having no luck with `setw` and `setprecision` as my compiler just tells me they are `not defined`.

`cout << "Total     : " << setw(2) << total << endl;`

total outputs: `Total     : 12.3961`

I'd like it to be: `12.40` or `12.39` if it's too much work to round up.

Comment: My bad, forgot it and edited it in.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to include `<iomanip>` and provide namespace scope to `setw and setprecision`

```
#include <iomanip>
std::setw(2)
std::setprecision(5)
```

try:

```
cout.precision(5);
cout << "Total : " << setw(4)   << floor(total*100)/100 << endl;
```

or

```
 cout << "Total : " << setw(4)   << ceil(total*10)/10 << endl;
```

iostream provides precision function, but to use setw, you may need to include extra header file.

Comment: Are there no other ways to format it without including other libraries? I ask this because my professor is super strict, and I'm assuming he doesn't want us to explore more libraries than the ones we learned in class aka `iostream` and `cstring`.

Comment: `setprecision(2)` displays `12` not `12.39`. How to display decimals?

Comment: @eveo `<iomanip>` is part of the C++ standard library. A good professor should not forbid you to explore the internet about good solutions. If you can explain why you included another file of the *standard library* (it's not another *library*), it should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @eveo This (`12` instead of `12.39`) is because `setprecision` defines (per default) the number of *significant* digits, not the ones after the decimal point. Note that for large values, it will use the exponential form. If you always want to have 2 digits after the decimal point, as it seems to be the case for me, you have to use the fixed number format (also write `std::fixed` to `std::cout`); see my answer with an online view.

Answer (score 21):

Use `cout << fixed` or `cout.setf(ios::fixed)`, and `std::cout.precision(<# of decimal digits>)` as in the following (using the Clang-503.0.40 compiler included with OSX Mavericks):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace std;

   float loge = 2.718;
   double fake = 1234567.818;
   cout << fixed;
   cout.precision(2);
   cout << "loge(2) = " << loge << endl;
   cout << "fake(2) = " << fake << endl;
   cout.precision(3);
   cout << "loge(3) = " << loge << endl;
   cout << "fake(3) = " << fake << endl;
}
```

The output from this is (note the rounding):

```
loge(2) = 2.72
fake(2) = 1234567.82
loge(3) = 2.718
fake(3) = 1234567.818
```

This is the simple version.  In lieu of using `cout << fixed;`, you can use `cout.setf(ios::fixed);` (for displaying scientific notation, replace *fixed* with *scientific*; both will set the number of digits to the right of the decimal point).  Note the cout.precision() is also used to set the number of digits displayed in total on either side of the decimal point if the format flags do not include *fixed* or *scientific*.  There are tutorials for this on the Internet.

Answer (score 13):

To also include the trailing zero, it isn't sufficient to set the precision. You also have to change the floating point format to *fixed* format, which uses the number of digits as told by `setprecision` as the number of digits *after the decimal point*:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << v;
```

[Working online example code](http://ideone.com/fAgESu)

Comment: For this to work you need to add this to your includes:

    #include <iomanip>

Answer (score 9):

If you want the trailing zero from rounding, you can use the C function `printf`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    float v = 12.3961;
    std::printf("%.2f",v); //prints 12.40
}
```

Compared to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    float v = 12.3961;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << v; //prints 12.4
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it?

Comment: @leemes he's asking how to get formatted precision output. Isn't he? At least that's what I read.

Comment: Hmm... I think this was my mistake. Your answer is correct. However, I don't like that you want to fall back to a C function like `printf`. And your C++ solution doesn't print the correct output as he wanted it to be (with the trailing 0). [By the way: you said leading instead of trailing]

Comment: @leemes Yeah, I don't like using C functions either but for formatted float input it's much better than `std::setprecision` in my opinion.

Comment: @Rapptz that's the opinion I was looking for, I agree with you. Weird how C++ don't have a better way than our older C buddy.

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro Since this was written, there is now [`{fmt}`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) and `std::format` in C++20 so this is out of date actually.

Comment: @Rapptz wow almost identical to [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) in python 3+ thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```cpp
std::cout << std::format("Total     : {:.2f}\n", total);
```

or the `fmt::format` function from [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that integrates formatting and output making it even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1f6Yddq8r)):

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("Total     : {:.2f}\n", 12.3961);
}
```

Output:

```
Total     : 12.40
```

This uses the IEEE754 default rounding mode (round to nearest even) so you'll have to round up yourself ([How do I round up/down a decimal place of a float value? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35107354/471164)).

Answer (score 3):

This is a little dirty...

```
template <typename T>
string sFormat(const char *f, T value)
{
    char buffer[64];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f, value);
    return string(buffer);
}
```

And do things like this :

```
cout << "Result :" << sFormat(" %5.2f", 3.14) << sFormat(" %5d", 2300) << endl;
```