# Converting from Radians to Degrees

Tags: c++, math, visual-studio-2015, physics

I'm building a small Physics engine and I'm having trouble converting my Radian value to Degrees using `atan`, as I need an angle to output in Degrees only.

Firstly, I have an `x` and `y` value, and I need to find an angle using `atan`, so I divide y by x like so:

```
angleDivide = yN / xN;
```

Then, before putting this value into `tan`, I attempt to convert it to Degrees like this:

```
angleToDegrees = angleDivide * (3.14 / 180);
```

Then I place angleToDegrees into `atan`:

```
angle = atan(angleToDegrees);
```

But when I'm displaying `angle`, I'm, still getting radian values.

Please could you tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix this?

Comment: That is a horrifically bad approximation to pi. **First**, use `M_PI` if it's defined, please, or else define it to `LDBL_DIG_10` digits precision. **Second**, you should be converting the _output_ of `atan()` from rads to degrees, not the input (which is just a slope). **Third**, you should use `atan2(y,x)` and not `atan(y/x)`.

Comment: Um... Firstly, your text says you want to put the value into `tan`, but the code then uses it in `atan`. So, is it for `tan` or for `atan`? Make up your mind. Secondly, if this is for `atan`, then why are you converting it? The argument of `atan` is not an angle. It is tangent value. Tangent is neither "radians" nor "degrees". Tangent is a unitless value. Converting "radians to degrees" for something that is not an angle makes no sense whatsoever. It is the *result* of `atan` that you might want to convert to degrees. The result, not the argument.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to calculate `radians=tan(y/x)` first.

Then you can convert it to degrees:

```
radians = atan(y/x)
degrees = radians * (180.0/3.141592653589793238463)
```

See the [reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan/) for atan:

On a side note, you also have to take into account what quadrant you are in to get the correct answer (since `-y/x` is the same number as `y/-x`)

Comment: About your side note: That's what `atan2(y,x)` exists for.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Just one question, my values come out as  '38.7464', which of course is a degree value, but is there a way I can shorten the decimal places?

Comment: @LucyLoo `char buf[64]; sprintf(buf, "%.1f", degrees); degrees = strtod(buf, 0);`

Comment: You really should change `3.14` to add some more decimals,

Comment: @LucyLoo If you're using C++ you should use its functionality to format the float. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432043/c-float-formatting.

Comment: I edited the answer to add more decimal places. I was wondering why my calculation was off by 0.04 degrees!