# Why do i get fractional part after converting integer to string? C++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    double number = 4, intPart, fractPart;
    fractPart = modf(number, &intPart);
    string stringIntPart = to_string(intPart);
    
    cout << fractPart << endl << intPart << endl << stringIntPart;

    return 0;
}
```

As an output I have:
0 (fractPart)
4 (intPart)
4.000000 (stringIntPart)
So why do I have these zeroes at stringIntPart and how to get rid of it? Thank you

Comment: As if you had done `std::sprintf(buf, "%f", value)`.

Comment: Well, you declared `intPart` as a `double`, so its string representation contains digits after the decimal point, like for any floating-point number

Comment: Your variables are of type `double`, which is a floating point type, and `modf()` works with floating point values.   String representation of floating point values is formatted - by default - to include decimal point and trailing digits.  Hence "those zeros".\

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3):

`intPart` is still a `double`, and gets formatted for text output with the default rules for `double`s (just because it's *logically* an integer value doesn't mean C++ is willing to spend the effort to do runtime checks to tweak precision dynamically; that's your responsibility if you choose to take it on).

To fix, you can either cast it to an integer type (risks losing data if the integer component is larger than 64 bits), or you can [use `iomanip` manipulators to change the formatting rules for floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14432043/364696) so they omit the data after the decimal point that you know will not exist, e.g. with:

```
cout << fractPart << endl << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << intPart << endl << stringIntPart;
```

(I left the `std::` prefixes in there on the added stuff, because [`using namespace std;` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696), and I prefer being explicit)